# Spring boot error "ERROR" dispatch for GET"/error" , parameter {}

Tags: spring-boot

I have made a simple controller in my first spring boot project but the controller is not directing it to JSP file and showing a Whitelabel page error
This is my project code

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I tried to show the output of the JSP file through the controller but got a Whitelabel page error

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Instead of posting code screenshots, [edit] the question and post relevant code in text format. It would be helpful to fellow SO users to help you in resolving the issue.